# Sending data from activity back to Fragment with finish function

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I had tried to send the data from Activity which is instantiated from a Fragment. Sending data from Activity back to fragment. I tried the following code

Fragment:

```
Instantiated the Fragment
    Intent intent = new Intent(Fragement.this,Activity);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activitiy.this, Fragment);
                intent.putExtra("Sent", "Something");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
```

Send result to fragment

> ```
> In Fragment trying to implement onActivityResult but not even able to define the method.
> ```

Comment: You can use view model and observe data in activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your activity using `startActivityForResult` like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Fragement.this, Activity);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

To get the result implement `onActivityResult` in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        // here you can retrieve your bundle data.
        String yourdata = data.getStringExtra("Sent");
    }
}
```

And In your `activity` do like following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("Sent", "String data"); 
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent );
finish();
```

**very important**

You must `override` `onActivityResult` in your **Activity(in which fragment is loaded)**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

For a complete example, [see this](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/17498/getting-a-result-from-activity-to-fragment)

Comment: in Fragment ActivityResult not overriding

Comment: Got Working now

Answer (score 0):

you must start the activity with startActviityForResult passing a request code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Fragement.this, Activity);
startActivityForResult(intent, myRequestCode);
```

Comment: how to get the Result in Fragment then.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment